# Open more server sockets than in `ulimit -n`

Tags: sockets, ulimit

`ulimit -a` gives me following:

```
vladon@vldn-dev:~$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31785
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31785
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

In practice on simple async server running here I cannot connect more sockets than specified in `open files` setting, i.e. more than 1024 (actually 1023).

If I increase it to `ulimit -n 10000` then I cannot open more than 10000.

Server is doing nothing actually, just accepting connections, it CAN handle more, but I cannot set `ulimit -n unlimited` or more than 10000:

```
vladon@vldn-dev:~$ ulimit -n 10001
bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

How to fully disable limit or avoid this limit?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56504/setting-ulimits-without-pam - In one sentence - you cannot increase limit of opened files above hard limit (`ulimit -H -a`) without proper permissions (root/user with CAP_SYS_RESOURCE).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These limits are (on linux) configured in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.
Here you can increase the number of file descriptors per file, by e.g. adding this line (as root):

```
*               hard    nofile      20000
```

Then verify using the `ulimit` command you used before.
On other unixes there is often a similar kernel parameter in the respective kernel configuration tool.

Increasing the per-process limit may in turn require you to increase the system-wide number of file descriptors. For this, again on linux, use:

```
# sysctl -w fs.file-max=100000
```